# How do I get PineScript to a specific order?

Tags: pine-script

[image: strate results]

Code in PineScript 4: two strategies that enter or different criteria; but as per the screenshot of the strategy results, Entry Long "E2" is exiting on Enter Long "E1" -- I need these associated correctly to be able to run two different systems in the same script.

```
    //@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

strategy.order("E1", strategy.long, when=crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)))
strategy.exit("E1", "E1", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * .90)    
    
strategy.order("E2", strategy.long, when=crossover(sma(close, 28), sma(close, 60)))
strategy.exit("E2", "E2", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * .80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `close_entries_rule="ANY"` argument in your `strategy()` call.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", close_entries_rule = "ANY", overlay=true)

strategy.order("E1", strategy.long, when=crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)))
strategy.exit("EX1", from_entry = "E1", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * .90)    
    
strategy.order("E2", strategy.long, when=crossover(sma(close, 28), sma(close, 60)))
strategy.exit("EX2", from_entry = "E2", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * .80)
```

You always welcome to check TradingView's [help center](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000619549). There is already solution about your issue.

Also
[kodify.net](https://kodify.net/tradingview-programming-articles) and
[pine-script-docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/)
will help you out.